# Equation to give a number of outputs based on change of one paramater

Tags: python, math, numpy

Here is my equation:

```
import math 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ha = 8.14
k = 0.0187
Do = 0.1738
Di = 0.0138
L = 3
F = 20 
Ta = 293
Ts = 113
pi = 3.14159265

Q = (pi*(Ta-Ts))/(((1/ha*Do))+(1/(2*k))*math.log(Do/Di)) * L

h = (Q*3600)/F
```

Basically, I want the outputs for when F = np.arange(20,100,10)

is this possible?

I tried

```
 a = np.arange(20,100,10)
 F = 20 + i 
 for i in range(a):
    print h
```

not sure why this doesn't work?

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `numpy` you should try to not use explicit loops, as `numpy`'s main virtue is to execute implicitly the loops with the speed of a compiled language.

To come to our problem, it is simply

```
F = np.arange(20,100,10) 
h = Q*3600/F
print h
```

where I use the array `F` just as a normal Python variable, and it's up to `numpy` magics to recognize the need for a loop.

Remember: you can use `numpy`'s arrays in your expressions just like you would use a scalar and, [as far as your usage is a sensible one](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), Python will compute an array-zed result.

---

*Side Note* use `np.pi` instead of `3.14159...`

Comment: aah, I should have remembered that operaors like +-*/ are defined to act on every element of an array. Upvote for this from me, well done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a function that takes in parameters. then you can call in that function based on a set of parameters. Bellow I show you an example with a `sin(x)` function because I'm sure you can figure out hwo to adapt it to your needs

```
import math

points = np.arange(20, 100, 10)

def sine(x, a=1.0, b=2.0):
    return a*math.sin(b*x)

for i in points:
    print(sine(i,b=i), end=" ")

-0.8509193596391765 0.9978032744219705 -0.8012247906768953 -0.6501275235748956 -0.2620839590180966 -0.7736233386803075 -0.5444763096196569 0.8272184413093554
```

this will call your `sin` function with various parameter `b` and will calculate it in different points `x`

The way you're doing it should always print out exactly the same number. Since you've already calculated everything. You don't have a function anywhere, and by putting it all in a `for` loop won't automagically change anything.

Unless it's some for of pandas magic in interpreter I don't know about. (In that case sorry, I'm not a big user of pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code is giving `Q` and `h` a specific value, and never changes that value again.

Explanation:

In the code below

```
Q = 4
W = Q

print(Q)
print(W)
```

you are saying: *name Q refers to value 4 and name W refers to the **current** value of Q*(that is 4, regardless whether Q changes later on or not).

If you type `Q = 10`, W will not change:

```
Q = 10

print(Q)
print(W)
```

Therefore you need functions that will be calculated each time you call them:

```
def Q():
    return (pi*(Ta-Ts))/(((1/ha*Do))+(1/(2*k))*math.log(Do/Di)) * L


def h():    
    return (Q()*3600)/F    


for i in np.arange(20,100,10):
    F = 20 + i
    print h()
```

The above explanation is a bit oversimplified, so you might want to check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhg_5424fsQ).

Comment: I'm trying to save the result ( h() ) in a list.... but it's not working... no idea why... I've tried to save it to a dataframe aswell..... doesn't work =/  any ideas?

e.g. a = []. a.append(h()), print a..... it gives a separate list for each result.

Comment: Above the `for` loop, use `my_lst = [ ]`, and inside the loop, below `h()` use `my_lst.append(h())`.